# Moving a sprite accelerometer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, hardware-acceleration

Im trying to, in cocos2d for the iPhone, move a CCSprite (in this case "player" up and down (the app is in landscape). How can I accomplish this? I have been unable to do so. ex.

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    player.position.x = acceleration.x * 10;
    NSLog(@"Accelerometer x value is %f\n", acceleration.x);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change position components like `x` and `y` directly. You have to set a new position instead, by assigning a `CGPoint` to the position property. Something like this:

```
[player setPosition:ccp( acceleration.x * 10, player.position.y )];
```

If you want to move the sprite constantly in the direcion of acceleration, you should increment the `x` value instead.. something like this:

```
[player setPosition:
    ccp( player.position.x + acceleration.x * 10, player.position.y )];
```

Technical background: You have to use `setPosition` or `position = ccp(xValue, yValue)`, because Cocos2D keeps a flag internally that indicates if the position has changed and if the sprite should be moved. Setting components like `x` or `y` directly won't do anything, because the flag only changes when you invoke the `position` setter.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for answering and for giving a fantastic answer! I plan on using the 2nd one. Just one sub question: How do I prevent the CCSprite from moving off the screen?

Comment: @Coder404 just clamp the x position to the desired bounds.. something like: `MAX(0.0f, MIN(screenWidth, player.position.x))` or simply use [ccClamp](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/_c_g_point_extension_8h.html#a9ece903bce575705f3e7fe2e81f011b0) to get a point within screen bounds

Comment: how could I implement MAX(0.0f, MIN(screenWidth, player.position.x)) into the code? like this? `[player.position    MAX(0.0f, MIN(screenWidth, player.position.x))];
 `

Comment: @Coder404 No, use `[player setPosition: ccp(MAX(0.0f, MIN(screenWidth, player.position.x)), player.position.y)]`... and ofc you'll have to replace `screenWidth` with the actual screen-width

Comment: I wanted to make it so the "player" could not move off the screen when the device accelerates